# Can't access public member of public static class inside public class (all in a separate jar)

Tags: java, android

Well, that's a mouthful of a title. It gets my point across, though. Here's the gist of my code, inside the jar:

```
public class NetworkShared {
    public static class LoginRequest {
        public String Username;
        //...
```

Then, to access it, I'm doing something like this:

```
NetworkShared.LoginRequest request = new NetworkShared.LoginRequest();
request.Username = "example"; //this is the problem line
```

It's when I try to access request.Username that I have a problem. Eclipse says the field NetworkShared.LoginRequest.Username is not visible. I'm puzzled because it's public all the way down. Java's not my main language, so I might be missing something. Does anyone know?

EDIT: I might add that this on Android. NetworkShared is in its own JAR and I've added it to the build path. Nothing else is wrong except for accessing request.Username.

Comment: Could you cut / paste the exact error as Eclipse gives it.

Comment: "The field NetworkShared.LoginRequest.Username is not visible"

Comment: If you right-click, do you get any auto-fix options about changing visibility somewhere?

Comment: It was a problem with Eclipse. I restarted it and all was fine. :P I've come to expect things like this from this IDE...

Comment: Why we NEVER hear this kind of question from users of other IDEs? Those IDEs have bugs too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conclusion:** Seems like this was an Eclipse refresh problem with a referenced JAR.

It should work. A top-level class is implicitly `static` so basically `NetworkShared.LoginRequest` is a correct way to identify the LoginRequest class. You are doing it the right way.

My answer is not to your eclipse problem -- it is to your Java question -- so at least you can get your Java related worries out of the way.

Outside the fact that your eclipse might have a bug (would not the first either), could you please compile the following code in your eclipse? You might have trimmed down your original code to something that actually works.

**NetworkShared.java**

```
public class NetworkShared {
    public static class LoginRequest {
        public String Username;
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NetworkShared.LoginRequest o = new NetworkShared.LoginRequest();
        o.Username = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: His code does work. Strangely enough, if I import the JAR into a new project, it works fine. So on a hunch, I decided to restart Eclipse. Miraculously, the problem is gone. It seems like Eclipse wasn't loading the new JAR because I had forgotten to make the member public before. I did delete the old JAR and re-add it to the project, but the problem persisted. After restarting Eclipse though, everything is fine. Thanks!

Comment: Ok -- so most likely an Eclipse refresh problem with the referenced JAR :)